# Does anyone know how to use AWS App2Container(A2C)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

AWS App2Container (A2C) is a recently launched feature by AWS. It is a CLI tool to help you lift and shift applications that run in your on-premises data centres or on virtual machines so that they run in containers that are managed by Amazon ECS or Amazon EKS. Since there is not much info on the internet about this, apart from the AWS document so does anybody knows how to implement it and what are the dependencies required for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly new service so most people will be relying on reading at the moment.

For JAVA applications the [setup instructions on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app2container/latest/UserGuide/start-containerize-java-app.html) indicate that you just download the app2container package and then run the following over your code

```
sudo app2container containerize --application-id java-app-id
```

For .NET applications the [setup instructions on Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app2container/latest/UserGuide/start-containerize-dotnet-app.html) indicate that it is exactly the same process, run the install file and that will have all dependencies.

The best way to try and implement this will be by following these tutorials step by step. Also remember at this time it is JAVA or .NET only.